# How to extract data after passing istream var to a function

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream

I am currently running a command line input program for class that extracts data from the command line argument, sticks it in an **ifstream** then passes it by reference to a function wherein I must extract information from the file.

First, I understand that"

```
ifstream coursesIn (argv[1]);
```

Will put my input filename into a courseIn variable of type ifstream. From here, I can perform operations such as .open(argv[1]); in order to extract the data necessary.

What comes next is that I'm to pass the variable to a function called processEnrollments(coursesIn)

whose prototype looks like:

```
processEnrollments (std::istream& courseFile);
```

Once I put the variable inside the function and am inside the function, my professor provided this code:

```
void processEnrollments (istream& courseFile, istream& enrollmentRequestsFile,
         ostream& reportFile)
{
int numCourses;
courseFile >> numCourses;

// Create the arrays we need
//!! Insert your code here
}
```

Firstly, I have no idea what he is trying to do with the first two lines inside the function, and secondly, I can no longer perform my .open(argv[1]) method in order to extract the data from the filename.

Outside the function I believe I can get everything I need, but after passed, I'm at a loss.

thank you for any help provided!

Comment: See [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). The [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) constructor, which accepts the file name, will have opened the file already so there is no requirement to call `open()`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems that you simply don't know what `istream`s are and how to use them. When you say "outside the function I believe I can get everything", are you by chance talking about using `scanf()` and other C-style `stdio.h` functions?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read more about streams.

The declaration

```
ifstream coursesIn (argv[1]);
```

creates a variable `coursesIn`, so long you are right, but it also *opens* the file with the file-name provided by `argv[1]`. If you do like this you don't need to `open` it later.

As for the function, the first line in it declares an integer variable, and the second reads an integer from the file `courseFile` and stores it in the `numCourses` variable.

And lastly, remember that all input streams have the same base, so if you can read input from e.g. `cin` you can also read input from a file.

Comment: I'm trying to; I've read the O'Reilly documentation, C++ ref, and the Malik textbook, but can't find an answer specific enough on simply what 'ifstreams' do.

thank you; but now I'm having another problem.

When I pass basic test case (a .dat file with, on line 1, a number 4) into the program through command line, when I cout numCourses, it prints a 0.